# Redirect the output to an already running program

Tags: io-redirection, gdb

I have a program running on terminal 1 and waiting for input from stdin. I programmed this program so it is vulnerable to buffer-overflow. I want to change it's flow to function2() within the program so I opened GDB in terminal 2, attached it to the program in terminal 1 using its PID and found out the address of function2().

Now I want to use [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) in third terminal to create a certain output and redirect this output to the program in terminal 1. How do I do it?

PS: I'm new to this kind of exercise and do not know if there's a better way of doing this. Please let me know if there is.

Comment: The `TIOCSTI ioctl` can spam random terminals with input e.g. https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/tty/ttywrite.c

Comment: @thrig: I can spam a random terminal with input too. Simply echo anything and redirect it to /dev/pts/<terminal_number>. But the question is would it be redirected to the stdin of the program waiting on that terminal. In my case it doesn't.

Comment: @7_R3X you miss the point that [thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/128228/thrig) is making. The referenced `ttywrite.c` program will put data into the terminal's input stream as if it had been typed on a keyboard. This is what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: @roaima: Yup! That's exactly what I need. Thanks for confirming.